# php_value and php_flag throwing errors in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I just moved web hosts, and I get errors in my .htaccess about php_flag and php_value not being defined. It worked fine on the other host.

This is what my .htaccess looks like:

```
php_value display_errors On
php_flag magic_quotes 1
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 1
php_value mbstring.http_input auto
php_value date.timezone America/Los_Angeles
```

The whole thing:

```
php_value display_errors On
php_flag magic_quotes 1
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 1
php_value mbstring.http_input auto
php_value date.timezone America/Los_Angeles
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
DirectorySlash Off
# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

Options -Indexes
```

What's going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Comment: `php_flag magic_quotes 1` <--- this is a reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeally bad idea

Comment: @zerkms A friend wrote it for me. What does it do?

Comment: what if you try to google? PS: don't trust your friend about anything related to programming since now (in case if you want to become a good developer)

Comment: thanks for the heads up d: @zerkms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new hoster is running PHP in CGI/FCGI/another SAPI mode. Setting PHP options like that in `.htaccess` files is only supported when PHP is run as apache module. Therefore the new server throws an internal error.

You can use [htscanner](http://pecl.php.net/package/htscanner) PECL package for older PHP versions and the [user.ini.files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) since PHP 5.3 (this is definitely preferred).

For the former htscanner solution wrap the php relevant lines inside of the `.htaccess` files in

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value ...
  php_flag ...
</IfModule>
```

For the latter new `.user.ini` solution create a file `.user.ini` in the root directory of your project, insert

```
display_errors=On
magic_quotes=On
magic_quotes_gpc=On
mbstring.http_input="auto"
date.timezone="America/Los_Angeles"
```

and remove the corresponding lines from the `.htaccess` file.

### Security and deprecation

`display_error` setting to `on` in a production environment is not a good idea. `magic_quotes` is a deprecated feature for a long long time meanwhile. If you can, you should rewrite your scripts. If you are using a more recent version of PHP (like 5.4) this feature is not even available anymore.